# How can i restore an Archived dynamic link accidently?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have two dynamic links in my firebase dynamic links which we are already using in our app so i just accidentally archived both links, now i am trying to unarchive those links but not getting any.

Please let me know what way i can retrieve those links to my firebase console as those are very important to me.

Thanks

Comment: i'm also looking for an answer to this. any luck anyone?